# Creating 250+ ETLs in SQL Server / SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis, etl

I have frontend access to a database but in order to get backend and do any type of meaningful analysis, I have to extract the data to CSVs and then upload them to my own SQL database. I have to use SQL Server.

The data has 250+ tables and I want to update them weekly. I've been using SSIS to create ETLS but I know I'm not working efficient. Any classes or advice anyone has to learn?

TIA

I tried learning via youtube and posts but I'm not finding a lot of advice for someone who hasn't built a database before.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you have access to create CSVs why not load directly to your DB. i don't know what kind of relationship you have with the DB team, but honestly the easiest way is to restore a back up.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/design-the-full-load-and-delta-load-patterns-in-ssis/

Comment: Ok, you load all of the data today. Next week happens and then what do you do? Are you going to remove all the existing data and replace with the current extract of data (truncate and reload pattern) or do you need to keep track of data that no longer exists in the source system (incremental load)?